# Test accounts for twitch

Tags: twitch

I am developing an application that will let users login via Twitch.
We already support Facebook login.

For Facebook, testing was easy as through a developer account I could create 2000 test accounts and signup using them one by one.

For twitch, I could not find anything similar. I am signing up everytime, verifying the email and then testing. Is there an elegant solution to this?

(I hope this won't be marked inappropriate as this is not a programming question)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitch does not have any api to create test accounts.
https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/creating-test-users/3803

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy way to approach this,
Although [Baba Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twitchaccountmaker/) has made a really descent tool for that, which creates temporary emails and verifies them.

I think it's the easiest approach you can get.
There are few others in the market, but *babas* probably the best.